# Appium: How to select element on drawable canvas without help of attributes?

Tags: appium

I am using Appium for automated testing. I want to select an element on the drawable canvas. 
I know how to find an element by attributes. But I want to find an element on drawable canvas without the help of attributes.

Is there any possible way to achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

Since Appium 1.8.2 there is a strategy [FindsByImage](http://appium.io/docs/en/advanced-concepts/image-elements/). It has limited interaction possibilities with the elements (in comparison with ones based on attributes):

- click
- isDisplayed
- getSize
- getLocation
- getLocationInView
- getElementRect
- getAttribute (only visual attribute)

At least you can verify whether an element is visible, read its boundaries and be able to click.

Under the hood, this approach works through the OpenCV library, thus you have to configure your Appium by installing additional npm packages. 
In addition, you need to take into account, that image recognition is a non-deterministic process and requires some tweaking (e.g. adjusting thresholds) in order to make your tests stable.

Hope this helps.